# Date histogram every half a month

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

How to write an interval that groups by every half a month? Rather than `1M` I want something like `1/2M` to group by from the first to the 16th and from the 16th to the end of the month, every month. Is there a way to do so?

I don't want to end up doing an interval on each day and then calculate manually my results as it's not clean and it would be resource hungry, is there a simple way to do so using setInterval? (in Elasticsearch or Elastica I don't care, I just want the algorithm behind it, thanks!)

```
$date_grp_agg = new \Elastica\Aggregation\DateHistogram('date');
$date_grp_agg->setField('date')->setFormat("MM-yy")->setInterval('1M'); // This one
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither `0.5M` (half month) nor `2w` (2 weeks) are supported, but you could try to use a number of days, i.e. `15d`.

```
$date_grp_agg->setField('date')->setFormat("MM-yy")->setInterval('15d');
```

Granted, it will not fit months perfectly, i.e. it won't start on the 1st and end on the last day of the month, but it can get you close to the kind of interval you're looking for.

Comment: I can't allow myself to be close, it needs to be exactly these same days, but if it's not possible I'll need to think of another way, thank you anyway :)

Comment: You can also use a `date_range` aggregation into which you give the boundaries yourself.

Comment: But that won't allow it to calculate manually the interval for a few years if I manually limit it each time :/